# R grepl with dynamic search pattern

Tags: r, dplyr, grepl

I have a data frame, `df`, having one column of different names. I have variable data frames, e.g. `search_df` or `search_df1` containing search words which I would like to search via regex in the name column.
If the word has been found write it into a new column, e.g. `df_final$which_word_search_df`.
If more than one word has been found I would like to paste the results together.
The result should look like `df_final`.

```
# load packages
pacman::p_load(tidyverse)

# words I would like to search for
search_df <- data.frame(search_words = c("apple", "peach"))
search_df1 <- data.frame(search_words = c("strawberry", "peach", "banana"))

# data frame which is the basis for my search
df <- data.frame(name = c("apple123", "applepeach", "peachtime", "peachab", "bananarrr", "bananaxy"))

# how I expect the final result to look like
df_final <- data.frame(name = c("apple123", "applepeach", "peachtime", "peachab", "bananarrr", "bananaxy"),
                       which_word_search_df = c("apple", "apple; peach", "peach", "peach", NA, NA),
                       which_word_search_df1 = c(NA, NA, "peach", "peach", "banana", "banana"))
```

That is my current solution but as you can see it is not dynamic. I type in manually every search word instead of automatically going through all the search words.

```
df_trial <- df %>% 
  mutate(which_search_word_trial = ifelse(grepl("apple", name, ignore.case = T), "apple", ""),
         which_search_word_trial = ifelse(grepl("peach", name, ignore.case = T), 
                                          paste(which_search_word_trial, "peach", sep = ";"), which_search_word_trial)
  )
```

The example I am sharing is just a minimal one. For the actual use case `df` will have ~200k rows and my `search_df` will have ~1k rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do the following.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  mutate(which_word_search_df = str_extract_all(name,str_c(search_df$search_words, collapse = '|')),
         which_word_search_df1 = str_extract_all(name, str_c(search_df1$search_words, collapse = '|')))

#         name which_word_search_df which_word_search_df1
# 1   apple123                apple                      
# 2 applepeach         apple, peach                 peach
# 3  peachtime                peach                 peach
# 4    peachab                peach                 peach
# 5  bananarrr                                     banana
# 6   bananaxy                                     banana
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your df as input (not the df_final): Here is an "automatic" way to do it by providing the name of the search dataframes:

```
n = c('search_df','search_df1')

for(i in n){
  a= (lapply(get(i)$search_word, function(j){grep(j, df$name)}))
  a=stack(setNames(a,get(i)$search_word))
  df[,paste0('which_word_',i)]=NA
  df[a$values,paste0('which_word_',i)]=as.character(a$ind)
}
```

The output is directly stored in `df` but you can change this easily by copying `df` to `final_df` and then use this one in the two last lines.

output:

```
       name which_word_search_df which_word_search_df1
1  apple123                apple                  <NA>
2  applebum                apple                  <NA>
3 peachtime                peach                 peach
4   peachab                peach                 peach
5 bananarrr                 <NA>                banana
6  bananaxy                 <NA>                banana
```

Lemme know if it worked for you